# Android Read Html span li and ul tag using jsoup lib

Tags: android, html, jsoup

Hello all I am new to read html from webpage using jsoup lib

This is my basic html:

```
<ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
<li class="level0 nav-3 level-top parent">
    <a href="mylink.html"
       class="level-top"><span>ABCD_MAIN CAT</span></a>
    <ul class="level0">
        <li id="level1nav-3-1first"><a class="arrow"
                                       href="mylink.html">SUB CAT
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li><span><a
                        href="mylink.html">SUB TO SUB CAT1
                  </span></a></li>
                <li><span><a
                        href="mylink.html">
                    SUB TO SUB CAT2</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>


        <li class="level1 nav-3-1 first"><a href="mylink.html">
            <span>SUB CAT(HERE NO SUB TO SUB CAT)</span></a>
        </li>


        <li><a href="mylink.html" class="see-all"><span>SUB CAT(HERE NO SUB TO SUB CAT)</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
    </ul>
```

In to this I need to read all cat(category) it's link sub cat and its related link and sub to sub cat with link..

How can I do this?

Please help

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please go through this tutorial 
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can do parsing something as follows :

```
String webpageContent = <your html page>;
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(webpageContent);
Elements liTags = doc.select("li"); //this will select all li tags
for (Element litag : liTags ) {
  // parse each litag to get your desire content
  you can use litag.attr, litag.html() , outerHtml()
}
```

refer [this link](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html) to know other properties of element class